Error calling expo-router navigation.goBack() on Android 7.0
I'm developing a React Native application with Expo and I have an error:

Error: Exception in HostFunction: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

It is triggered when I click on the back button of my application to return to the previous <Stack/.>. I'm using a physical device running Android 7.0. I also have the error on Android 7.0 emulator.
On android versions > 10 I have no errors. Nothing on iOS either.
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation, useRouter } from "expo-router";
import { scale } from "@/utils/responsive";
import { Image } from "expo-image";

const ButtonBackHeader = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const router = useRouter();
    
    function goingBack() {
            if (navigation.canGoBack()) {
                navigation.goBack();
            } else {
                router.push("/");
            }
    }
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={goingBack}>
            <Image
                source={require("@/assets/icons/chevron-left.svg")}
                style={{ width: scale(36), height: scale(36) }}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

export default ButtonBackHeader;

Thanks in advance for the help
I tried to wrap with a try/catch, navigation.replace(), InteractionManager nothing change
